# ViewPager fragment understanding

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've some questions regarding ViewPager and fragements.
I've an activity (play) with a ViewPager and two fragments (playfrag1, playfrag2) with one textview in every fragment.

-When the fragement is loaded? already when the main activity is launched? or when i switch to this fragment using the pageview?
- I want to prefill all fragments when the main activity is called, whats the common way doing this? should i pass the values to the fragment or call some functions from the main activity?

Thanks!

Comment: I would call a function from the mainactivity in onResume of the fragment

Comment: your fragments will be initialized when the activity created which where the viewpager is initialized , and they will be destroyed accordingly when they out of scope. of course you can use offset number to the viewpager so they remain.

Comment: ok thx. i tried to call a method from main activity to set the textview text. the textview is always null but you said it will be initialized when the activity is created!  public void settext(String lala)
    {
        TextView tvfrag2 = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.txtfrag2);
        tvfrag2.setText(lala);
    }

Comment: Where are you calling getView?